# FxCop folder missing

Tags: fxcop

What is the issue?
I am trying to install FxCop 10. To install that, Microsoft Windows SDK 7.1 is required. I installed the SDK. Now, to install FxCop, I have to run FxCopSetup.exe, which is supposed to be located in the folder %ProgramFiles%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Bin\FxCop. But, that folder is missing.

What I did to try to fix it?
I searched the web to fix the issue, and I tried a couple of workarounds that were suggested in a few discussions including (1) not doing a full installation of the SDK and (2) uninstall SDK, reboot, re-install SDK and reboot.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Btw, I'm running Windows 7 (if that's relevant).

Answer (score 43, accepted):

In my SDK install, there is an FXCop folder: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\FXCop. Is there an FxCop folder *somewhere* in you SDK install? Apparently it's been moved...

Alternately, I have the FxCop installer on my Dropbox: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1311259/FxCopSetup-10.0.exe

Comment: Thanks, Grant! There is no FxCop folder in the SDK install. But, I just installed FxCop 10 using your setup executable.

Comment: The only direct link to FxCop 10 I found on the internet, thank you!

Comment: Thanks for sharing it. At my current network speed, its impossible to download the whole SDK

Comment: @Grant Palin Thanks for sharing. And yes, this is the only direct link to FxCop 10.0!

Answer (score 0):

It's in Program Files, not Program Files(x86).  I realized this when running a repair on the windows sdk when I couldn't find the folder, and seeing where it was copying files.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me when I only selected the "Tools" option to install.