# Has FxCop been removed from the Windows SDK for Windows 7?

Tags: .net, winapi, fxcop

I have been searching high and low for the definitive answer as to how to get hold of the latest version of FxCop and despite the release notes saying:

> 6.3.6 FXCop Setup is Now Located Under the Window SDK “\Bin” Directory.
>   The installer for FXCop, fxcopsetup.exe, is now located in [Program Files]\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Bin\FXCop.

It clearly is not there (and not anywhere in fact)

Can anybody confirm this or at least enlighten me as to where I can get hold of it?

Comment: The SDK installer skips installing a bunch of tools when it detects that Visual Studio is installed.  You'd normally use the Analyze + Run Code Analysis menu option in VS to run it.  It isn't clear from the question whether that applies and what version and edition of VS you have.

Comment: See this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13548470/fxcop-installation